# General expression for a state that is close in trace distance to a pure state

Tags: quantum-state, trace-distance

Suppose we are given that a quantum state $\rho$ is close in trace distance to a pure state $\vert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\vert$. That is

$$\|\rho - \vert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\vert\|_1 \leq \varepsilon,$$

where $\|A\|_1 = \text{Tr}\sqrt{A^\dagger A}$.

Is it true that $\rho = (1 - \varepsilon)\vert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\vert + \varepsilon\vert\psi^\perp\rangle\langle\psi^\perp\vert$? This seems to ignore the possibility of off-diagonal terms so I think it's not the most general way to write $\rho$. So what is the most general expression for $\rho$?

The motivation for this comes from the fact that the trace distance and fidelity satisfy the Fuchs van de Graaf inequality

$$\|\rho - \vert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\vert\|_1 \leq \sqrt{1 - F(\rho, \vert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\vert)}$$

and equality holds if $\rho$ is also pure. Here, we have a state that is almost pure and I am trying to show that the Fuchs van de Graaf inequality is also "almost" an equality.

Comment: well, there definitely are other pure states close enough to the given pure state, and that expression for $\rho$ (which is always non-pure) does not cover them

Comment: That state is always rank $2$. For any state you can find a full rank state that is $\epsilon$ close. (Just mix with the maximally mixed state with an appropriately chosen weight).

Comment: Your question is ill-posed, there are plenty of states in the $\varepsilon$-ball and surely there is no general expression. You motivation seems to come from geometry and fits better to closeness in 2-norm, i.e. Hilbert-Schmidt norm. Do you want find an orthogonal decomposition? Then you have to take that in operator space. While being $\varepsilon$-close means that the overlap of $\rho$ with $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi |$ is at least $1-\varepsilon$, the projection onto the orthocomplement of $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi |$ is in general not psd and does not even have trace one.

Comment: @MarkusHeinrich I see - so we have $\rho = (1-\varepsilon)\vert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\vert + \varepsilon\cdot\text{something}$ but you're saying we can't really say anything about the "something" part.

Comment: @user1936752 Note that I was talking about closeness in *2-norm*. You always have the unique orthogonal decomposition $\rho = \delta |\psi\rangle\langle\psi | + X$ with $0\leq \delta = \langle \psi | \rho | \psi \rangle \leq 1$ and $X$ is Hermitian and $\langle \psi | X | \psi \rangle =0 $. It is generally *not a convex combination* of states. $X$ is generally not psd and its trace is $1-\delta$. If $\| \rho - |\psi\rangle\langle\psi | \|_2 \leq \varepsilon$, then you can deduce that $\delta \geq 1-\varepsilon$ and $\|X\|_2 \leq \varepsilon$.

Comment: @MarkusHeinrich thanks! Actually, aren't the Schatten norms nonincreasing so if I have $\|\rho - \vert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\vert\|_1 \leq \varepsilon$, then it also follows that $\|\rho - \vert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\vert\|_2\leq \varepsilon$?

Comment: @user1936752 Yes, all norms on finite dimensional spaces are equivalent anyway. So if $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small for one of the norms the other norms should also be small.

Comment: @user1936752 yes, that it is true. However, note that although all norms on finite-dimensional spaces are equivalent, the norm constants are usually dimension-dependent, here $\|X\|_2 \leq \|X\|_1 \leq  \sqrt{d} \|X\|_2$ ($d$ is the Hilbert space dimension). This can make a huge difference if we compare approximations in different norms. In this case, approximation in 2-norm is exponentially cheaper for a $n$-qubit system than approximation in 1-norm.